# Excel FILTER and spill area potentially not being big enough

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm happy enough using FILTER in my Excel spreadsheets, and understand the concept of spill areas...

Just wondering if, as I've only got ten rows for the spill area to run into but three columns (so, conceivably 30 cells), there's any way of getting any filter results from 11-20 to go into the cells of the second column and 21-30 to go into the third column...

Isn't a biggie, as I could redesign what I've got - but looks quite neat and tidy at the moment...

Any pearls of wisdom would be greatly appreciated...

I haven't tried anything, as I can't think of anything to try...

Comment: `WRAPCOLS` is your friend ... `=WRAPCOLS(FILTER( ... ),10)`

Comment: Will give that a go and report back... thanks, Ike :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `=WRAPCOLS(FILTER( ... ),10)`

It will spill the results of the filter to multiple columns - per each 10 values.